# Finite dimensional distribution of a stochastic process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose $Y,Z$ are i.i.d. random variables, obeying the standard normal distribution, and let $$X(t)=Y \cos(\theta t) + Z \sin(\theta t)$$for $\forall t \in \mathcal{R}$ and a fixed $\theta$. Then $X_t(Y,Z)$ is a stochastic process.

Then what is the finite dimensional distribution of $X_t$? That is, for any given k moments $t_1,t_2, \cdots,t_k$, what is the joint distribution $P(X_{t_1}=x_1,\cdots,X_{t_k}=x_k)$ ?

What I've done :

1. It is not hard to show that for a fixed $t$, $X(t) \sim N(0,1)$.
2. I wonder  if for different $t_1$ and $t_2$, $X(t_1)$ is independent of $X(t_2)$. If it is, following $P(X_{t_1},\cdots,X_{t_k})=P(X_{t_1})\cdots P(X_{t_k})$, I can conclude that the joint distribution is actually a K-dimensional standard normal distribution.
3. I've tried to show that $X(t_1)$ is independent of $X(t_2)$ by definition $P(X_{t_1},X_{t_2}) = P(X_{t_1})P(X_{t_2}\vert X_{t_1})$, but that yields a tricky integration.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No, $X(t_1)$ and $X(t_2)$ are not independent. Just consider for instance $t_1 := t$ and $t_2 := t+2\pi$ for some fixed $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The process $X(t)$ is stationary, mean zero, and Gaussian. All you need to do is calculate the covariance function $\gamma(m)=\mathbb{E}(X(t) X(t+m)).$

Comment: That the process is Gaussian is not so obvious to me. Could you explain a little bit? @ByronSchmuland